# What is the opposite of compulsion?

Tags: word-choice, antonyms

If I am acting based on a compulsion, then I am acting because I am forced to do so.  I have given up my power to chose.  What is the opposite of this?  If I decide to act after careful analysis and decision, what is this called?

Comment: Out of your free will, maybe.

Comment: You want an antonym for compulsion or one word for "acting after analysis?"

Comment: acting with deliberation is **not** the opposite of acting from compulsion.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are acting of your own *volition*, which [Merriam Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/volition) defines as "the power to make your own choices or decisions".

Or you could say you are acting *of your own accord*, which [Wiktionary](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/of_one%27s_own_accord) defines as "voluntarily, without being told to or asked to".

Comment: Volition is exactly the word I needed

Answer (score 1):

You can say you're acting ***"deliberately"*** or ***"with careful deliberation"***.

From the MacMillanDictionary.com:

> **"Deliberately"**:
>
> 1) with a definite intention, not by chance or by accident
>
> Examples: "You did that deliberately, just to annoy me.",
>
> "Police believe the fire was started deliberately."
>
> "Her voice was deliberately cool."
>
> 2) in a slow careful way
>
> Example: "He spoke deliberately, considering each word carefully."

Answer (score 0):

There are several notions of compulsion.

One opposite of compulsion not yet mentioned is **agency**.  Another is **autonomy**.